# Problem using mv

Tags: mv

I was trying to use the `mv` command but I made a mistake. I had a file called `relazione` in a directory and I was trying to move it to another directory with the same name, so I typed:

```
mv  relazione  /relazione
```

The terminal didn't let me, so I typed:

```
sudo mv  relazione   /relazione
```

It worked. Then I realised that nothing had moved.

I did everything while I was working with `gdl`. I would like to know what I have done and if this can somehow give some problem with `gdl`.

Comment: It’s not clear for me what you are asking. I have no idea what gdl is. But I’d suggest you think twice before you run a command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files and directories on Unix-like systems (including Linux) are organized in to a tree. At the bottom (or the top, if you're a computer scientist—they have funny trees) is the trunk or "root directory". The path for that is `/`. From that, you can build other paths: `/relazione` is a directory that is immediately off the root.

Normally, your personal files are somewhere inside your home directory (typically `/home/username`—so `home` is off of the root directory, then `username` is off of `home`. )

What you did isn't likely to break anything (though it may make it hard for you to find your files—e.g., if you use a GUI, it'll start looking in your home directory, or maybe even a directory inside that). If you're using a file indexer, those files will probably no longer be indexed. Etc. You can just move it back, with something like:

```
sudo mv -i /relazione ~/relazione
```

`~/` is a quick way to specify your home directory (to save typing).

However, there is something that **will break your computer**: that habit of running things with `sudo`. When you get an error trying to run a command, there is a reason for that! Permissions are there to (among other things) protect the system from destruction, and `sudo` removes all restrictions. You should use it as sparingly as possible, and only when you understand the command you're about to run.

Answer (score 0):

The command you posted moves the file `relazione` to the root ('/').

Comment: can this give any problem with other programs?

Answer (score 0):

With the command `sudo mv relazione /relazione` you have moved the `relazione` folder in your root directory (`/`). If you want to move the `relazione` file try:

```
mv /path_to_relazione_file/relazione /path_to_relazione_folder/relazione
```

Comment: Can this give me any problem with other programs? Or with the program i was in? (I launched that command while i was working with gdl by using $ and then the command)

Comment: Don't worry it won't cause you problems. You can move again that folder with `sudo mv /relazione /wherever_you_want_to_move`